# How to use Or condition in PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data

I need to use two or more conditions on different fields in a `Repository` that extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

For example:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person,String> {
    Page<Person> findByCreatedUser(String createdUserId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This method should filter by `createdUserId=Person.createdUserId` or `createdUserId=Person.userId`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I found the answer.

Page findByCreatedUserIdOrUserId(String createdUserId, String userId, Pageable pageable);

Answer (score 0):

Just define a method and add the @Query annotation as outlined in the documentation:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person,String> {
    @Query("......")
    Page<Person> findByCreatedUser(String createdUserId, String userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Or do as you have done although method names can get a bit unwieldy In this approach.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I found answer in a different way. But for your approach how to mention the Or Condition?

Comment: Method name is not important this way. You supply the jpql in the @query rather than having framework derive it. Can be used to avoid long method names!

Comment: I got your point. Can use your approach when it is too long. My question is, how to mention the Or condition inside the @Query ? Any example would help.